# Rigify Rig not centered

Tags: rigify

When I generated a rig using a tutorial, in the video the rig was in the same place as the armature.  However, when I generated my rig it was off center.  It wasn't in the same location as the meta rig and was located further down and off to the right.  I tried moving it in edit mode but I think that's going to mess somethings up because the bones are still parented to that original location.  What went wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Upload your Blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ so that we can have a look. It sounds as if the origin of either the armature or model aren't in the same place or you haven't applied the scale to the armature or model..

Comment: This will happen if you accidentally change the 3D origin of the meta rig.  You can do this if you edit the meta rig and move the entire armature for example.  To check this, move the 3D Cursor to the origin, and in object mode, set the 3D origin of the meta rig to the 3D cursor (right click and select origin -> 3D cursor).  generate a new rig. It should be in the right position.